# Login and management over telnet in embedded linux

Tags: c, linux, scripting, authentication, embedded

We are moving over from C on AVR to an embedded Linux platform.

Appreciate some 'best practice' suggestions on how we should program (e.g. bash scripting/c program) a telnet 'management console' to first login to the device (we now have a working kernel and able to run simple 'hello world' c program) and then allow user to enter commands like 'set msc', where the console will prompt for apn? username? password ... etc.

Do we just write a c program as a 'telnet server' and have it running waiting for a telnet client connection over a socket? Or are there other approach in embedded Linux? Thank you.

Comment: Many embedded solutions use normal telnet server, together with BusyBox and uses "custom" commands to handle special needs for the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would probably be to use an existing solution. For instance, we use [openssh](http://www.openssh.com/) for our embedded boards (ARM and x86 platforms), together with a serial console for debug. Both of these will give you both login-handling and all that for free.

To add, our kernel and rootfs are created with [PTXdist](http://www.ptxdist.org), so we can easily add, handle and cross-compile new applications and packages from a standard host computer. It works just fine, and also makes it very easy to actually port complete applications to other platforms.

Comment: Thank you, please correct me. So, after openssh is done with its authentication, you will pipe any rx/tx characters from the openssh to a c program for further device management/configuration etc?

Comment: No. openssh simply gives you a remote terminal console on the machine, from which you can do (basically) anything that you can do if you were using the machine itself directly. I may have misunderstood your question though - if you're after something to configure your own application directly, instead of rather the machine in general, a custom solution might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I suppose we have to write our own custom C program. Basically, once the SSH/Telnet session is connected to the remote user, he/she would be able to enter custom commands like "set msc" which the device will prompt for new device parameters from the user, like "Enter APN:" for instance. Hope this is clear. So, we should head down a custom C program route? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend using `dropbear` (lightweight `sshd`) on the target so that communications with the device are encrypted, only include `telnetd` if you must.

No matter which way (or both) you choose, you need to setup some scripts to start dropbear/telnetd. This will wary depending on your distribution.

Then setup an account on the device that will be used to administer the system and make that users shell be your custom CLI. (This info is stored in /etc/passwd)

The CLI can then be implemented in whatever language seems appropriate, it will just read/write stdin/stdout which will be connected to either a telnet or ssh client on the user side. All telnet logic is handled by `telnetd` which will in turn call `login` to manage authentication of the user. Both of these applications are available with `busybox` which will most likely be a part of your root filesystem.